# React checklists changing checked / unchecked based on query string information with React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a check list like this

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Apples" checked={this.props.fruits} onChange={this.fruitClickHandler.bind(this)} />Apples</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Bananas" checked={this.props.fruits} onChange={this.fruitClickHandler.bind(this)} />Bananas</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Oranges" checked={this.props.fruits} onChange={this.fruitClickHandler.bind(this)} />Oranges</label>
```

And what I would like to do is when clicking these update the query strings with the relevant information.

Updating the query strings is done in the parent component so all I do here is sent the information up with the event handler

```
     fruitClickHandler = (event) => {
        log.debug('Fruit - fruitClickHandler(): ', event);
        log.debug('Fruit - fruitClickHandler(): target.checked', event.target.checked);
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.props.updateHandler({fruit: event.target.value})
        }
        else {
            this.props.updateHandler({fruit: undefined})
        }
    }
```

This works but there's a problem ...

I'm using 'defaultValue' to tick the checkbox if it is selected in the query string, I've used this fine with dropdown lists or single inputs ... but now trying to do this with a 'group' of checkbox inputs my problem is that when you select one checkbox it selects them all

The problem is this bit

```
checked={this.props.fruits}
```

It's doing what it's told what I need is something like

```
checked={this.props.fruits == "apples" : checked}
```

But this doesn't feel very React and I don't think this is likely to be the way I should be going about this

My question is in the world of React is this the way I should be trying to achieve this?

I hope my questions clear, let me know if I need to give further details or explain anything a little better

Comment: this.props.fruits === 'apples' should be ok if you ask me.

Comment: Well that seems to work so maybe I was just over thinking it .. that probably is the way to go